# /proc/net/dev and /sys/class/net/ bogus network interface names

Tags: linux, networking

I am constructing a list of network interfaces to monitor based on the contents of /proc/net/dev. But I am getting some bogus interfaces in the list:

```
__tmp1104705027
__tmp974528607
```

Where do those come from?

They also show up in /sys/class/net/:

```
# ls -1 /sys/class/net/
eth0
eth1
eth2
eth3
lo
sit0
__tmp1104705027
__tmp974528607
```

For now, I think I'll just ignore anything starting with __tmp, but I'd like to know what they are and where they come from.

This is on a recompiled CentOS 5.3 kernel: 2.6.18-128.7.1.el5.tvh.7PAE #1 SMP PREEMPT

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This appears to be a bug with CentOS and broadcom drivers, detailed here: http://bugs.centos.org/view.php?id=2791

Most people seem to require a

```
modprobe -r *drivername*
modprobe *drivername*
```

or even a reboot (arg) to fix. The link also has suggestions of other workarounds.